# Copying back log files from container to host

Tags: docker

I'm learning docker and made a simple python3 scrip that reads CSV from local file system > does some processing to the data > and writes back to a log file.

when running a container, I'm able to `--mount` host file so that PY script running in container is Abel to read, however I'm unable to copy back the log file form container to host system.

my PY script as follows (stripped down to minimal for easy readability):

```
df = pd.read_csv('csvs/file.csv')
print(df)
df.to_csv('logs/log_file.txt', mode = 'a', index=False, header=False)
```

the run command I execute (based on other examples in SO) is as follows:

```
$docker run --mount 'type=bind,source=/Users/my_name/doc/csvs,destination=/app/csvs' 
image:latest python read_write_test.py cp /app1/logs /Users/my_name/doc/logs
```

how can I modify the `run` command so that after the container finishes running the script, the log files are copied form container volume back to host filesystem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the volume option :

```
$ docker run -v /your/host/shared/folder:/container/shared/folder image:latest python read_write_test.py cp /app1/logs /Users/my_name/doc/logs
```

This way, the volume will be shared between your host and your container, and you won't need to write it back since you will be writing directly on the source.

Or if you want to have a "in" and a "out" folder :

```
$ docker run -v /your/host/shared/folder/in:/container/shared/folder/in -v /your/host/shared/folder/out:/container/shared/folder/out image:latest python read_write_test.py cp /app1/logs /Users/my_name/doc/logs
```

Also, it seems to me that your commands should be in the CMD of your Dockerfile... (or do you have a specific reason to do it this way?)

```
CMD ["sh","-c","/path/within/container/to/your/read_write_test.py >> /shared/out"]
```

(for example)

Comment: Thanks a lot! this works. I thought `--mount` (being more verbose and explicit) is recommended flag vs `-v` (at-least for beginners), as per docker doc: https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/.... re: CMD, yes I'm just practising and playing around with Dockerfile try different options

Comment: Yes, --mount is definitely more verbose. In your case, it should work the way you wrote it. Are you sure you did not miss-write some path? Like using "/Users" instead if "/usr" ?

Comment: my bad, typo error.. app1 instead of app.. but your response was still useful to understand we can add multiple -v flag in same run command :). Thanks a lot!